# How do I call a function in C++ that returns a string from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have the following function in C++ that I want to call from C#:

```
std::string getString();
```

**How do I best do this (using Pinvoke)?**

Am I correct in assuming that return allocated memory from C++ to C# is problematic and that it would be better (easier) to allocate a large string in C# and then pass it on to C++ for writing?

In this case I guess I should wrap the C++ function with C ?:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void get_string(int size, char *buffer)
    {
       call getString and strncpy to buffer 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with returning an `std::string` - the C# CLR can handle only primitives, unless you use manage C++. I would go for the latter (passing a `char*` to the C++ implementation)

Comment: As you wrote... Just remember that `strncpy` isn't guaranteed to add the terminating `\0`, so you should add it manually.

Comment: @xanatos: thank you very much for your help! What do I declare the buffer as in C#? byte [] or do I use StringBuilder?

Comment: wouldn't that be at least `wchar_t*`? Or is that the stone age calling?

Comment: @xanatos: or do I simply declare the buffer as char[] in C# and then use StringBuilder to compose a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical way to do it is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void get_string(int size, char *buffer)
{
    std::string str = getString();
    strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), size);
    buffer[size - 1] = '\0';
}
```

C# side:

```
[DllImport("NativeLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void get_string(int len, [Out] StringBuilder sb);
```

and then (very important! You must pre-size the `StringBuilder`)

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
get_string(sb.Capacity, sb);
string str = sb.ToString();
```

You can use a `char[]`, but it is more complex, because then you have to manually "trim" the `\0`.

There is a more complex way to do it with one less copy of memory... But it is a little more complex:

C++ side:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void get_string(void (*func)(const char*))
{
    std::string str = getString();
    func(str.c_str());
}
```

C# side:

```
[DllImport("NativeLibrary", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void get_string(StringFromIntPtr.FromIntPtrDelegate func);

public class StringFromIntPtr
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void FromIntPtrDelegate(IntPtr ptr);

    public string Value { get; protected set; }

    public void FromIntPtr(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        Value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    }
}
```

Then you use like this:

```
var sfip = new StringFromIntPtr();
get_string(sfip.FromIntPtr);
string str = sfip.Value;
```

The point is that you pass to the C++ code a delegate to a C# method that knows how to handle a raw pointer to a string (through the use of `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` for example), and the C++ code uses it. Note that it would be much easier to do this in C++/CLI (because you wouldn't need the delegate, the C++/CLI can use both `std::string` and `System.String^`)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++/CLI, you can return System::String too. You can construct the System::String from getString().c_str()